# "password_digest can't be blank" and "password can't be blank" errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postman, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to create a user via Postman as shown in the screenshot, but getting errors:

[image]

This is a rails app created with an `--api` option.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates_format_of :email, with: /@/
  validates :password_digest, presence: true

  has_secure_password
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
    # GET /users/1
    def show
      render json: User.find(params[:id])
    end
    # POST /users
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            render json: @user, status: :created
        else
            render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:show, :create]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `user_params` method expects the attributes nested in a `user` hash. Change the response to:

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "...",
    "password": "..."
  }
}
```

Btw the `validates :password_digest, presence: true` line is not needed because [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) has validations build in and ensures internally that a password is present.

Comment: Thanks. I just had to wrap in double quotes the hash.

{
  "user": {
    "email": "askar@example.com",
    "password": "asdfasdf"
  }
}